# Include PHP file via AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, include

I'm trying to call a .php file located within a subfolder of my plugin via an ajax request. I've tried lots of different ways of including, including get_template_part, but I just can't seem to get the content to render. I feel like I'm probably doing this wrong, but I'm not sure what to try next. The file is located one directory above and then into another directory called "Templates".

`tps_show_modal` is a custom function, the 2nd argument is the content of the modal box. (this function is confirmed working elsewhere).

Any help is appreciated.

**PS.** I also need to pass a variable (`spaceID`) to the included file, hence the use of `set_query_var()`.
**PPS.** Working in a Wordpress environment

Here's my ajax request:

```
$(document).on('click', '.uiSpaceTitle', function(e) {
    var spaceID = $(this).attr('data-spaceid');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
        context : this,
        data: {
            action: 'tps_get_space_info_block_ajax', spaceID:spaceID
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var wWidth = $(window).width();
            var dWidth = wWidth * 0.8; //this will make the dialog 80% of the window
            tps_show_modal('Space Info', response, false, 'OK', dWidth);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's my php function it calls:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_tps_get_space_info_block_ajax', 'tps_get_space_info_block_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tps_get_space_info_block_ajax', 'tps_get_space_info_block_ajax');
function tps_get_space_info_block_ajax() {
    set_query_var('spaceID', $_REQUEST['spaceID']);
    ob_start();
    include('../templates/space-info-pane.php');
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    $result = json_encode($result);
    echo $result;
    die();
}
```

Comment: Add after your ajax success function this: succes: function(response){ ... }, error: function(e, t, a) { console.log(e) } and tell me if there is something

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't see anything in the console when adding that in.

Comment: Ok, in your function if you comment the content and add an echo with anything, it shows?

Comment: Yes, but still no luck on that actual include. I've checked the file path, and I believe I'm using the correct include syntax?

Comment: What if instead of doing the include right now, you make a function where you call that include, and call that function as a callback in the ob_start("newFunctionWithThe Include")?, can you try it?

Comment: No change unfortunately. :(

Comment: what you expect from response to return?? and what is the output of `console.log(response);`

Comment: Right now, it's just literally an echo "testing" that I'm trying to return from the file, to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Nothing is in the console (no errors or values). The include is just not working for some reason.

Comment: And the echo "testing" instead the include? works?

Comment: Yes, if I just echo something directly, it works. Super weird! I feel like maybe this is a Wordpress include issue. Maybe I can't directly access files for include inside a plugin file? Seems strange...

Comment: AH! I figured it out. It was indeed an issue with Wordpress's rules about including files I think. Using this worked: include(plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ).'templates/space-info-pane.php');

Comment: Ok, that is something, let see, I used to use the set_query_vars with the get_template part, can you describe me the tree? is this the functions.php?  where is located the space-info?

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking something like that, I mean with the location of the file, great :)

Comment: Thanks for the help though, that one had me stumped for a while. :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that Wordpress is weird when including files in plugins. I had to use this instead of a vanilla include file path:

```
include(plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ).'templates/space-info-pane.php');
```

This comment on the Wordpress codex page got me there: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#comment-2085